# How to link the extra user profile table to the existing aspnetusers table in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a **MVC 5** application with visual studio 2013, I have created a extra user profile table which supposed to link to the aspnetusers table by **userID** with instructions from this link:  **http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customizing-users-profile-to-add-new.html**, but I tried few different ways to link these two tables, but it is not working when debugging, and my user customer user profile model class is as below:

```
public partial class User_Profile_Info
{
    [Key]
    public string User_ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Agency_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal? AccessLv_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Salutation { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Middlename { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalQ1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalA1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalQ2 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalA2 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalQ3 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string PersonalA3 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal Status_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date_Created { get; set; }

    public virtual Access_Levels Access_Levels { get; set; }

    public virtual Agency Agency { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public virtual User_Status User_Status { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to set up the foreign key in the SQL custom profile table to link to the aspnetusers table, but got error in the run time after mapped from code first to model classes, I am just wondering if possible to set up entitiy framework with sql database separately without using Entity Framework's Code First Database Migration as long as both parties match, becuase  when I try to integrated with both tables with code first, it encountered various errors and take ages and not able to fix.

I am still new to this MVC ASP.NET Identity System, please advise!

Comment: Before diving into this... it's worth to ask why don't you extend the `UserProfile`? why do you want another different table?